BeeWare конвертация в apk
первый раз создал приложение на python beeware когда запускаю в корне проекта
briefcase create android
выдает, что надо принять лицензию и надо запустить команду:
 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache\tools\android_sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses

но когда запускаю то система не находит путь к такому файлу
все это делал в PyCharm помогите решить
